# Help with rails collection_select [edited]

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, collections

I have been trying to implement [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DependentSelectbySilVeR) jquery plugin to my app.I need help trying to output something like this

```
<select name="user[university_id]" id="user_university_id" class="selectable">
    <option value="1" title="uni1">Uni1</option>
    <option value="2" title="uni2">Uni2</option>
</select>
```

by using a rails helper...the problem is the helpers never seem to output a title attribute to the option tags.. which is critical for this plugin

please help,
thanks in advance

Edit:
my current rails code is

```
<%= f.collection_select(:university_id,University.all,:id,:name) %>
```

which simply outputs

```
<select name="user[university_id]" id="user_university_id">
        <option value="1">Uni1</option>
        <option value="2">Uni2</option>
    </select>
```

So basically what I need is a way to also add title attribute to my options.

Comment: Which jQuery plugin are you using? And please at the rails code, you have written so far.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add it with jQuery, if you don't go the rails helper route:

```
$(function () {

    $('select.selectable option').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).text());
    });

});
```

Comment: But that defeats the purpose of using rails helpers... dont see the reason to do that but appreciate the jquery tip