# Rails helper "Collection Select"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, collections

I have the exact same problem as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143478/help-with-rails-collection-select-edited) , since no one has answered, I decided to repost:

> I have been trying to implement this
>   jquery plugin to my app.I need help
>   trying to output something like this

```
<select name="user[university_id]" id="user_university_id" class="selectable">
<option value="1" title="uni1">Uni1</option>
<option value="2" title="uni2">Uni2</option>
</select>
```

> by using a rails helper...the problem
>   is the helpers never seem to output a
>   title attribute to the option tags..
>   which is critical for this plugin
>
> please help, thanks in advance
>
> Edit: my current rails code is

```
<%= f.collection_select(:university_id,University.all,:id,:name)%
```

> which simply outputs
>
> ```
> <select name="user[university_id]" id="user_university_id">
>         <option value="1">Uni1</option>
>         <option value="2">Uni2</option>
>     </select>
> ```
>
> So basically what I need is a way to
>   also add title attribute to my
>   options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with rails collection_select \[edited\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143478/help-with-rails-collection-select-edited)

Comment: If it wasnt a duplicate before, my answer (unintentionally) certainly made it one :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about rolling your own helper?  I just copied this code out of the [rails source](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/56bb5504dd1fc7314f1bd7a489ddaff973668be2/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb) and then changed the name and added the title.

```
  def options_for_select_with_title(container, selected = nil)
    return container if String === container

    container = container.to_a if Hash === container
    selected, disabled = extract_selected_and_disabled(selected)

    options_for_select = container.inject([]) do |options, element|
      text, value = option_text_and_value(element)
      selected_attribute = ' selected="selected"' if option_value_selected?(value, selected)
      disabled_attribute = ' disabled="disabled"' if disabled && option_value_selected?(value, disabled)
      options << %(<option title="#{html_escape(value.to_s.downcase)}" value="#{html_escape(value.to_s)}"#{selected_attribute}#{disabled_attribute}>#{html_escape(text.to_s)}</option>)
    end

    options_for_select.join("\n").html_safe
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit hacky but you could do something like:

```
$('#user_university_id option').each( function(){
    var optText = $(this).html();
    $(this).attr('title', optText);
})
```

This would assign the title with the text contents of the option. Alternatively you could do something more arbitrary using a generated ID.